# EF Code First: Need to update column length and data on production server

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

We have an `ASP.NET MVC Core` app created with `Code First` approach - using `SQL Server 2012`. The app is already running in production where we need to change the length of a column from `varchar(25)` to `varchar(30)`. The approach we've used to make the above change is as follows. This approach seems long-winded. **Question**: Is there a better and faster way of doing it? We're using `ASP.NET Core 1.1.1` with `VS2017`

**Our Approach** [so far]:

**A**. On Developer machine, change the corresponding Model as:

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar(30)")]
public string ColumnName { get; set; }
```

**B**. Run `PM> Add-Migration ...` and `PM> Update-Database ...` commands in `Package Manager` console of `VS2017`

**C**. Re-load the data to the corresponding table with changed column length

**D**. Re-deploy the database to production.

**E**. Re-deploy the project to production.

Comment: Increasing column length does not require column drop/recreate/reload, it may be performed on "live" database. How many rows of data you have in production DB (how long you think SQL will perform ALTER TABLE command)?

Comment: @Dmitry I'm aware of `ALTER TABLE` command etc along with changing the length in `SSMS`. But this is an MVC `Code First` application that requires any schema change in a Db to be performed via Model in order to keep the Model and corresponding Db table in sync. You probably may be thinking of the old fashion way where one could just change the db schema and load the data via sql scripts etc.

Comment: No. i'm not :) As you know `Update-Database` generates DDL and executes them. With some simple code you may apply all required updates during app startup. Automatically. Only new/required. So the question is - how long will your changes apply to production DB, is acceptable to "hang" app for this period of time? If yes - just do it.

Comment: @Dmitry What you mentioned above is similar to what we're looking for. Could you please either point out to an online article or explain it as `Response`? App's "Hang" will not be an issue in our case.

Answer (score 0):

It "migration time" (actual/real time required by RDBS to execute DDL and update whole production database) is not very big (you agree to take your app offline for this time, and you don't expect "command timeout")  than you may run migrations during app startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // your current app.UseXxx() calls

    using (var tempScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var db = tempScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<YourDbContext>();
        db.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```